# Search api prisma mysql where ANY

Tags: next.js, api-design, prisma

I'm trying to implement search api for my project. However I'm not sure how to accomplish this task whenever I got many variables which need to be included into query. For example how can I search for ANY character using this piece of code?

```
jobs = await prisma.jobOffer.findMany({
            where: {
                OR: [
                    {
                        title: {
                            search: searchTerm?.replace(' ', ' | ') || undefined
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        description: {
                            search: searchTerm?.replace(' ', ' | ') || undefined
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            include: {
                category: true,
                company: true
            }
        })
```

UPDATE:
as stated in [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined#the-effect-of-null-and-undefined-on-conditionals), OR returns no results if undefined. On the other hand, AND returns all results if undefined, so I took this approach:

```
jobs = await prisma.jobOffer.findMany({
        where: {
            AND: [ 
                   {
                       OR: [
                            {
                                title: {
                                    search: searchTerm?.replace(' ', ' | ') || undefined
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                 description: {
                                          search: searchTerm?.replace(' ', ' | ') || undefined
                                 }
                            }
                        ]
                   }
                 ]
        },
        include: {
            category: true,
            company: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: What does it mean search for any character? You want to check that field contains something? Like length > 0, or what?

Comment: If searchTerm is empty then retrieve all offers. I don't want to do this IF statement before query, because I have bunch of similar variables which I want to place into the query (like searching by employmentType, salaryRange). At the moment, if searchTerm is empty, query doesn't retrieve anything

Comment: Just pass undefined instead of a search then?

Comment: So I get no results when I pass undefined. I want all job offers if I pass undefined here, instead of ANY

Comment: I just tried it with similar schema and it works fine, if you pass undefined then you get all unfiltered results. So maybe you are doing something wrong

Comment: Found reference about undefined and null in prisma.
([prisma.io docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined))

I am not getting results because I use OR conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that if all conditions in `OR` operator are undefined then you will get no results ([docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined#the-effect-of-null-and-undefined-on-conditionals)). I was under impression that you always have at least one condition there, but now I see that you are using one search term to check all the fields. In that case you can just check that `searchTerm` exists and then use `OR` operator, like that:

```
jobs = await prisma.jobOffer.findMany({
      // Such condition is to make TS happy, considering `type searchTerm = string | undefined`
      where: !searchTerm ? undefined : {
        OR: [
          {
            title: {
              search: searchTerm.replace(' ', ' | '),
            },
          },
          {
            description: {
              search: searchTerm.replace(' ', ' | '),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```